# Understanding a csproj assembly reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reference, .net-assembly, csproj

I am using VS2010 and I tried to add a few assemblies from local hard disk to my C# project through file reference. Peeking into the `csproj` file, I found sometimes the file reference appears as

```
<Reference Include="name">
```

However sometimes it appears as

```
<Reference Include="name, Version=xxx, Culture=neutral, 
                                          processorArchitecture=MSIL">
```

What could cause the difference?

---

Inspired by k3b's answer, I did another test. I created a new class library project.

1. Add a file reference. The initial value of *Specific Version* in *Properties* pane is *False*. The `csproj` file look like

   ```
   <Reference Include="Name">
     <HintPath>...</HintPath>
   </Reference>
   ```
2. Change *Specific Version* in *Properties* pane to *True*. VS adds version in the `Include` attribute.

   ```
   <Reference Include="Name, Version=...">
     <HintPath>...</HintPath>
   </Reference>
   ```
3. Change *Specific Version* in *Properties* pane to *False* again. VS adds a child element `SpecificVersion`.

   ```
   <Reference Include="Name, Version=...">
     <HintPath>...</HintPath>
     <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
   </Reference>
   ```

So it seems that the rule is:

- When *Version* is present in *Include* attribute and there is no `SpecificVersion` child element, the file assembly is configured to be Specific Version
- The `SpecificVersion` child element is only appended with value *False*.

One thing I still do not understand:

- For my new test project, if I remove the file reference and add it back again, it goes back to format in point 1, which is the default.
- For my existing project, if I remove the file reference and add it back again, I get back format in point 3. Although it also means that Specific Version is not used, I am wondering why it does not go back to format in point 1.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Which reference-type you get depends on how you link the assembly.

- select the referenced assembly in the project-explorer
- go to the properties-page

there you find a boolean flag "specific Version"

- true means: the assembly must have version=xxx
- false means: ignore the assembly version

(I only have a german-vs2010 so the english translation for the german "Spezifische Version" may be slightly different)

[update]

I tried the following using vcs2010-express german

add reference with **default SpecificVersion=False** : no version

```
<Reference Include="Castle.Core">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\lib\fluentNHibernate\Castle.Core.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

modified reference: **SpecificVersion=True** : added version

```
<Reference Include="Castle.Core, Version=2.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\lib\fluentNHibernate\Castle.Core.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

modified reference again: **SpecificVersion=False** : version remains and new element SpecificVersion

```
<Reference Include="Castle.Core, Version=2.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\lib\fluentNHibernate\Castle.Core.dll</HintPath>
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
</Reference>
```

It seems that the specific version is remembered but ignorede because of `<SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>`

Comment: are you sure? in my VS2010, `SpecificVersion` is a child of the element `Reference`. Is has no impact on `<Reference Version="..."/>` other that the attributs is ignored.

Comment: I did a test. The Specific Version initially is False. I then manually edited the csproj file to remove the version info. And then I changed Specific Version to True. I observed that VS inserted the version info. So it seems that it is somehow related to Specific Version. However, I am wondering now why VS does not remember my last change. Even I reset Specific Version to False and remove and readd the assembly reference, the version info is still inserted.

Comment: I confirm your observations. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: For projects dependening on other projects I noticed the following: "inherited"/transitive dll dependencies are referenced with version and specific set to false while directly set dll dependencies go without any version info.