# TFSbuildextension reference is wrong

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am getting the below error message

Summary: There were 0 failures, 1 errors and 0 warnings loading custom activities and services.

> Error: Could not load file or assembly 'TfsBuildExtensions.Activities,
>   Version=1.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The TFSbuildExtension.Activities.dll I have on the system and also the reference i have added is version 1.12.10.0, I am unable to find the file or reference where I need to modify my build definition to refer to 1.12.10.0, it is by default referencing to 1.12.0.0

Can you please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the reference in your XX.csproj file. More detail info please refer this question: [Understanding a csproj assembly reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578819/understanding-a-csproj-assembly-reference)

Comment: Thank you so much, this helps   . Meanwhile the actual issue we had was that the file we have been modifying is different to that of the file that was used for the build, this was now copied over and this has resolved the issue and i am able to build successfully